# Legendre Summations

Tags: number-theory, summation, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and put $$s(a, p) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{p} \left(\frac{n(n+a)}{p}\right) $$

Prove that if $(a, p) = 1$ then $ s(a, p) = s(1, p).$

I have no idea how to prove this, I have tried using Wilsons Theorem but haven't really got anywhere, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altered version to avoid fractions, since they seem to cause confusion here.

Hint: Find $b$ so that $ab\equiv 1\pmod {p}$.

Then show that $$n(n+a)\equiv a^2\cdot nb(nb+1)\pmod{p}$$

So $$\left(\frac{n(n+a)}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{nb(nb+1)}{p}\right)$$

Comment: Is this true for Legendre Symbols?

Comment: But my question is regarding Legendre Symbols and Summations, so does your equality still apply as they have different properties to normal fractions?

Comment: $n(n+a)$ has the same properties - it has nothing to do with Legendre symbols. I did say this is a hint, didn't I?

Comment: Since it made it to the review queue (probably due to its brevity), I assure you I didn't vote to delete.  But the last sentence, Thomas, in the comment above doesn't justify as an answer to someone who doesn't get what you are trying to hint at.  Don't try, when you haven't been understood, to simply default to the fact you identified it as a hint. That doesn't cut any slack as far as the answer's quality.

Comment: I would add more to this answer, such as why you would want to write it that way.

Comment: I believe the red part of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{p}\color{#C00000}{\left(\frac{\color{#000000}{n(n+a)}}{\color{#000000}{p}}\right)}$ was meant to be a [Legendre Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Comment: I know, @robjohn My last equation isn't true for fractions.

Comment: @user395914 It is wrong to think of Legendre symbols as any kind of fractions. Consider it just notation for a function - you could just as well write $L(m,p)$ instead of $\left(\frac m p\right)$. I've always disliked the "fraction-like" notation for Legendre.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Sorry, I saw the comment that you "didn't write any Legendre symbols" and then the last equation. I mixed up the $\pmod{p}$ above that equation into that equation. I understand now. I've always disliked that notation, too.

Comment: @robjohn Yeah, those early comments are about a previous version of the answer, where I wrote $\frac{n}{a}$ instead of $nb$.